# Linear mapping interval of numbers to [0,1]

Tags: math, language-agnostic, numbers

I know it should be trivial, but tonight I'm not finding a solution.
Suppose I have a series of float in a given range such [0.25, 1.0]. For example:

```
{0.25, 0.625, 1.0}
```

What's the correct way to transform them in order to map the [0.25,1.0] interval to [0.0,1.0]?
The example sequence should become:

```
{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}
```

Second question, how to generalize that? How is the correct way to map a given interval [a,b] to [0,1]?

Comment: Why does 0.375 map to 0.5?

Comment: mmm..maybe I'm wrong but the distance between 0.25 and 1.0 is 0.75. and 0.75 /2 is 0.375. So it's the medium value between 0.25 and 1.0, such as 0.5 is the medium value between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Heisenbug Not quite! I think you mean 0.375+0.25 maps to 0.5. I'm assuming you want a linear mapping, unless told otherwise... Are you really language agnostic, or do you want code formatted in some particular way?

Comment: @Heisenburg The midpoint is (a+b)/2 or (b-a)/2 + a. Not (b-a)/2. The midpoint between 2/8 and 8/8 is 5/8.

Comment: @Nicholas Wilson: Maybe I'm too tired tonight. Btw Yes I want linear mapping. And language agnostic. If you prefer a c-like pseudocode that's fine

Comment: @John Kugelman: yes right. fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun lin-map(list) :=
    mx = max(list), mn = min(list)
    return [ (x - mn)/(mx-mn) | x <- list ]
```